# Create a discord bot which logs all messages

Tags: python, discord

So I've looked into creating a python discord bot, and am wondering how to create a discord bot which logs everything. I want it to log messages, edits, deletes, invites, etc immediately to a text file. I saw .on_message() but I don't know how to actually get the message. Any ideas?(The purpose of this is to create a log for a school club discord server which would allow teachers to join. They cannot join unless they have a method of checking all communication between teachers and students. This bot would be run on the school servers)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the `Client` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#client), as all edits, deletes, invites, will be logged through the client. I can't help directly with code because I use `.js` not `.py`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, writing to a spreadsheet or database might be easier

I recently made a bot that does this, and uploads all messages to Google Sheets. You can [check it out here](https://github.com/Jumpyvonvagabond/cherub-public/). If you'd still like to make your own, this would be done with

```py3
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = str(message.author)
    content = str(message.content)
    userid = str(message.author.id) 
    messageid = str(message.id)
    time = str(message.created_at)
    link = str(message.jump_url)
    channel = str(message.channel)
    row = [userid,author,content,time,messageid,link,channel]
```

and then writing row to a spreadsheet or txt file for logging messages

```py3
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    row = [before, after]
```

and then writing row to a spreadsheet or txt file

```py3
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    message = message
```

and then writing message to message.

For more info on writing messages to files,

[Python Input/Output docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for txt files

[Python JSON docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for JSON files

[GSpread documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Google Sheets

[SQLite Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html) for Database Files